# How to fix if else not showing correct option

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int goodMorning() {
    printf("Good morning, Aman");
}

int goodAfternoon() {
    printf("Good afternoon, Aman");
}

int goodNight() {
    printf("Good night, Aman");
}

int main() {
    int get;

    printf("To see the magic enter the number b/w 1 to 3 -> ");
    scanf("%d", &get);

    if (get=1) {
        goodMorning();
    }
    else if (get=2) {
        goodAfternoon();
    }
    else if (get=3) {
        goodNight();
    }
    else {
        printf("WRONG INPUT");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in this code I have made the three function of goodMorning(), goodAfternoon() and goodEvening() and I am using this with if else statements I am not getting the desired output.

When I enter 1 it shows good morning Aman,
and, when I again enter 2 it show good morning Aman again.
and, when I enter 5 or any other number it shows good morning again..

Please help me to fix that..

Comment: Can't help unless you edit your code into the actual question as text.

Comment: Please copy the code in your message, don't link to an image of code.

Comment: _"in this code"_ - You must actually show the code too.

Comment: You have typos or serious errors. `get=1` is an *assignment* not a *comparison*. `get == 1` is a *comparison*. (same issue with the other two)

Answer (score 2):

A simple typo is your fault here. You are not using a test, but rather an assignment when you write:

```
if (get=1) 
{
    goodMorning();
}
```

Because `1` is true, then this *always* is true.

You want `==`.

```
if (get == 1) 
{
    goodMorning();
}
```

Please note a few other issues:

- Your `goodMorning`, `goodAfternoon`, and `goodNight` functions are specified as returning `int` but do not. Compile with warnings on.
- You do not check the return value from `scanf`. If it does not succeed, `get` is unitialized when your conditions check its value.
- You probably want to print a newline at the end of your outputs.
- **Opinion:** You have the option to move the check for invalid input (`scanf` not returning `1` or the input being out of range) *before* the rest of the code, as a sentinel of sorts, also returning `1` rather than `0` to indicate an error occurred.
- **Also opinion:** A switch statement could be used on `get`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int goodMorning() {
    printf("Good morning, Aman");
}

int goodAfternoon() {
    printf("Good afternoon, Aman");
}

int goodNight() {
    printf("Good night, Aman");
}

int main() {
    int get;

    printf("To see the magic enter the number b/w 1 to 3 -> ");
    if (scanf("%d", &get) != 1 || get < 1 || get > 3) {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (get) {
    case 1:
        goodMorning();
        break;
    case 2:
        goodAfternoon();
        break;
    case 3:
        goodNight();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` assigns the value `1` to `get`, and `==` checks if the value of `get` is equal to `1`. `get = 1` will always return `True` because the assignment process is successful. That is why your code always enters the first `if` statement.

However, when asking a question, it's better to use a code block instead of pictures.

Additionally, regarding your coding style, if a function only prints something without returning any value, you should use the `void` function type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int goodMorning() {
    printf("Good morning, Aman\n");
}

int goodAfternoon() {
    printf("Good afternoon, Aman\n");
}

int goodNight() {
    printf("Good night, Aman\n");
}

int main() {
    int get = 0;

    printf("To see the magic enter the number b/w 1 to 3 -> ");
    scanf("%d", &get);

    if (get == 1) {
        goodMorning();
    }
    else if (get == 2) {
        goodAfternoon();
    }
    else if (get == 3) {
        goodNight();
    }
    else {
        printf("WRONG INPUT");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see you have to add == into each if condition. I would also recommend to set unused var's to 0 or any value for effience and security. after applying those changes it should work

Comment: Initializing `get` is less important than checking the return value from `scanf`.